# EF Core 6: Make navigation readonly

Tags: entity-framework-core, navigation, readonly

```cs
    public class ParentClass
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string ID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [StringLength(80)]
        public string ChildID { get; set; } = string.Empty;  // login name

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ChildID))]
        public virtual ChildClass Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildClass
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string ID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

When I read a `ParentClass` entity from the database, I want the `Child` property to be read, too. But when I write a `ParentClass` entity to the database, I don't want the `Child` property to be written as well. In the context of `ParentClass`, it is a readonly property.

Setting `Child` to null leads to an error, because EF Core 6 expects valid data to be present. This happens before my controller is reached, so I have no chance to set the property's state to unchanged, like

```
_context.Entry(parent.Child).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

I have googled and also read some SO articles on this, but not found a solution.

How do I have to specify `ParentClass.Child` to be readonly and make EF Core ignore it when the property is null?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am looking at the same issue.  Thanks

Comment: @MarkLFT: See me below answer. That did the trick for me.

Comment: This seems like a very dirty workaround.  I get the making the classes null, and I don't think would cause too many issues.  But the remembering to set the Entity State for every entity prior to every save seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: I have very few functions per entity to save such entities to the DB. For each entity, I have a function that sets that State to EntityState.Unchanged for each property where that needs to be set, and call that function from every function that stores stuff in a table. That way I keep the stuff centralized and only have to modify a single function in case an entity changes. I have expanded my below answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a workaround for the issue. The child property has to be nulleable:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    // ...
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChildID))]
    public virtual ChildClass? Child { get; set; }
}
```

To keep this centralized, I have a single function per class that sets the property states accordingly:

```
void IgnoreProperties(MyClass ent)
{
    if (ent.Prop1 != null)
        _context.Entry(ent.Prop1).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    if (ent.Prop2 != null)
        _context.Entry(ent.Prop2).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}

[HttpPost("Add")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] MyClass ent)
{
    IgnoreProperties(ent);
    _context.Table1.Add(ent);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok(); 
}
```

Together with setting its state to EntityState.Unchanged, this led to EF Core not wanting to write the child property instance back to its DB table when the parent entity got changed.